# How to decrease the speed of my robot?

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am not able to decrease the speed of my real robot. If I am decreasing the speed from RVIZ by setting Velecoty Scaling and Accel Scaling then it is working fine. If I am giving the robot a trajectory from python code then it very fast does anyone have an idea of how can I be able to solve this issue?

I have tried few things:

1. By using set_max_velocity_scaling_factor and set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor function [as maintained in following post](https://answers.ros.org/question/346203/why-is-my-robot-moving-so-slow-with-moveit/).

   move_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)
   move_group.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.01)
   move_group.set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor(0.01)
2. I have updated `default_velocity_scaling_factor` and  `default_acceleration_scaling_factor` to 0.01 in joint_limits.yaml file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376226/how-to-decrease-the-speed-of-my-robot?/) by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1622 on 2021-04-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in case of `computeCartesianPath(..)` there is no support for scaling velocities/accelerations.
You can control the speed by using `retime_trajectory(..)`:

```
        waypoints = getMyWaypoints()

        (plan, fraction) = group.compute_cartesian_path(
            waypoints,
            0.01,
            0.0
        )
        plan = group.retime_trajectory(moveit_commander.RobotCommander().get_current_state(), 
                                       plan, 
                                       velocity_scaling_factor)
        group.execute(plan, wait=True)
```

---

Originally posted by [crnewton](https://answers.ros.org/users/59954/crnewton/) with karma: 71 on 2021-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-15**:
Thanks! it works

**Comment by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on 2021-05-27**:
moveit_robot_state = moveit_commander.RobotCommander().get_current_state()

**Comment by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on 2021-05-27**:
Also speed is actually the speed scaling factor.

**Comment by [crnewton](https://answers.ros.org/users/59954/crnewton/) on 2021-05-31**:
Updated my answer to be more generic. as @lorepieri commented.

**Comment by [robra](https://answers.ros.org/users/121281/robra/) on 2023-02-28**:
Hi, do you know how to implement this in c++? I looked into the `MoveGroupInterface` class [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/lunar/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html) here but couldn't find a `retime_trajectory` function

**Comment by [Jiang Zizhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/85564/jiang-zizhen/) on 2023-04-18**:
retime_trajectory is only available in rospy, no corresponding function in cpp

**Comment by [robra](https://answers.ros.org/users/121281/robra/) on 2023-04-19**:
Thanks, but just for reference, time parameterization can be implemented in c++ using the corresponding classes [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/master/moveit_core/trajectory_processing/include/moveit/trajectory_processing) and therefore the `retime_trajectory` is not needed in c++

**Comment by [Jiang Zizhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/85564/jiang-zizhen/) on 2023-04-19**:
hi, how to use it, could you please give a template code!